# Documents not shown in Firestore console

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have linked a Firebase project to my Android application. In the application, I have created an instance of Firestore which I use to add document from a data class (id to the document is allotted by Firestore itself) to the collection whose name is specified by me. It does gets stored somewhere in Firestore because I am also able to retrieve the documents I added, using get() method from the database through the application.

The problem is when I open the Firestore database console, it shows nothing, no collection and no documents as can be seen in the image below. The "obituaries" collection you can see in the screenshot, was created manually by me.

[Screenshot of Firebase Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrmEH.png)

I have done everything as per the Firebase documentation, from setting up an instance of Firestore to adding and retrieving documents to and fro database, but of no avail.

I found a glimpse of the solution today but do not exactly know how can I use this knowledge to see my documents in the Firestore console. I use Firebase Authentication also in the application. Earlier, I was using only one user account to add and get documents. But today, I uploaded some documents using another user account. When I try to get those documents, only the documents uploaded by this user were retrieved. The documents added by the earlier user were not retrieved. Same thing happened, when I logged back in using previous user account, here also on retrieving the documents added by the new user were not retrieved.

That means, the collection is being created under the respective users by Firestore.

The code to add new document to the "obituaries" collection is given below:

```
private fun postObituary(obituary: ObituaryClass) = runBlocking{
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    try {launch{
            db.collection("obituaries").add(obituary)
        }
    }
    catch (e: Exception){
        Log.i("PostObituaryFragment", "Error adding document", e)
    }
}
```

I have two questions:
1. How do I see this collection in Firebase console?
2. How do I retrieve the documents uploaded by other users (not the user who is currently logged in) in my app?

Comment: Show us a screenshot of your console.

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo , I have added the screenshot of console in the original question body.

Answer (score -1):

sir check your code you can override the file path in firestore use unique id or nuber to store all users directory

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I tried to get the document path: 
val docRef = db.collection("obituaries").document(doc_id); 
var path = docRef.path; Log.i("ObituaryDetailFragment","Path reference is $path");      
The result is: I/ObituaryDetailFragment: Path reference is obituaries/LEEGemjH9kmMRoQ0LGvc     
When I copy and paste this path in firebase console... still it shows an empty document. 
Also, there is no reference to the User in this path. 
Can you please show another way to get the correct path?

Comment: can you please give an example of how to override the file path in firestore using the unique id